# Wants to align drop down list to the center for drop down button2 in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, alignment, dropdownbutton

[image]

In flutter I wants to center align the drop down list.below is my current code can someone guide me regarding this. I wants to align it center just below the drop down button.Should I have to align text widget or is there any other property to set alignment of it

```
Center(
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                                child: Center(
                                                  child: DropdownButton2(
                                                    isExpanded: true,
                                                    items: items
                                                        .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                                              value: item,
                                                              child: Text(
                                                                item,
                                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                                  color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                                      255, 214, 130, 3),
                                                                ),
                                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                              ),
                                                            ))
                                                        .toList(),
                                                    value: selectedValue,
                                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                                      setState(() {
                                                        selectedValue = value as String;
                                                      });
                                                    },
                                                    icon: const Icon(
                                                      Icons.arrow_downward_sharp,
                                                    ),
                                                    iconSize: 14,
                                                    iconEnabledColor:
                                                        Color.fromARGB(255, 248, 150, 2),
                                                    iconDisabledColor: Colors.grey,
                                                    buttonHeight: 40,
                                                    buttonWidth:
                                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                                                    buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                        left: 14, right: 14),
                                                    buttonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                                                      border: Border.all(
                                                        color: Colors.black26,
                                                      ),
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                    ),
                                                    buttonElevation: 2,
                                                    itemHeight: 40,
                                                    // alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                    itemPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                        left: 14, right: 14),
                                                    dropdownMaxHeight: 200,
                                                    dropdownWidth: 300,
                                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                    dropdownPadding: null,
                                                    dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                    ),
                                                    dropdownFullScreen: true,
                                                    dropdownElevation: 8,
                                                    // dropdownOverButton: true,
                                                    scrollbarRadius: const Radius.circular(40),
                                                    scrollbarThickness: 6,
                                                    scrollbarAlwaysShow: true,
                
                                                    offset: const Offset(-20, 0),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
```

Comment: please provide your code clean

Answer (score 0):

This might be happeing because of `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` in `row` widget

Change this to `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start`

Or alternatively as @Ramji suggested:
, you could use `offset` attribute like:

```
offset: Offset(40, 0),
```